# Dúvidas sobre o float e erro de encoding

Tags: python

```
# coding: utf-8
peso = float(input('Qual o seu peso? (quilos)' ))
altura = float(input('Qual o seu tamanho? (metros)'))
imc = peso/altura**2
print('seu IMC é de', imc)
```

> Qual o seu peso? (quilos) 49.00
>
> Qual o seu tamanho? (metros) 1.62
>
> ('seu IMC \xc3\xa9 de', 18.670934308794386)

- Por que esses **\xc3\xa9** estão aparecendo na minha resposta?
- Como reduzir as casas decimais do `float`?

Comment: Que versão do Python está utilizando? Como está executando o código?

Comment: Veja se seu arquivo está salvo com o encoding utf8, é comum o arquivo não estar em utf8 e acontecer uns bugs assim, tente abrir o arquivo pelo sublime e clique em "File > Save with encoding > UTF-8".

Comment: Para reduzir o número de casas decimais, use round(imc,2) para duas casas decimais.